# Adding up floats within lists containing a particular string category

Tags: python

How can one add up float values connected to a particular category string that are in a list that contains strings and floats?

For instance, in the example below, how would I sum the values of 'CategoryA'?

```
List = [('CategoryA', 6.03), ('CategoryA', 14.97), ('CategoryA', 1.00), ('CategoryX', 4.32), ('CategoryD', 3.60)]
```

Comment: Could you please show what you've tried? What specifically didn't work? Could you provide an [mcve]? Unfortunately, with more information this question is to broad and will be closed as such.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using a sum function like so:

```
sumfora = sum(x[1] for x in List if x[0] == 'CategoryA')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tot_sum = 0
for category, val in List:
   if(category == "Category A"):
      tot_sum += val
```

This will give you the sum of Category A in `List` in the variable `tot_sum`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use pandas for this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(List, columns=['Category', 'Value'])
>>> df
    Category  Value
0  CategoryA   6.03
1  CategoryA  14.97
2  CategoryA   1.00
3  CategoryX   4.32
4  CategoryD   3.60
>>> df[df['Category'] == 'CategoryA']['Value'].sum()
22.0
```

Or if you want to see the sums for each category:

```
>>> df.groupby('Category')['Value'].sum()
Category
CategoryA    22.00
CategoryD     3.60
CategoryX     4.32
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```